Unittest for display extender fails at install SchemaIncompleteException: No schema for views.settings
i am trying to write a functional test for my module that ships a views display extender but it already fails at installing my module.
in my module.install file i have these lines that will add my display extender to views.settings config:
function my_module_install() {
  // Enable display extender.
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('views.settings');
  $display_extenders = $config->get('display_extenders') ?: [];
  $display_extenders[] = 'my_display_extender';
  $config->set('display_extenders', $display_extenders);
  $config->save();
}

And i have this simple test that extends ViewsTestBase
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\my_module\Functional;

use Drupal\Tests\views\Functional\ViewTestBase;
use Drupal\Tests\node\Traits\ContentTypeCreationTrait;
use Drupal\Tests\node\Traits\NodeCreationTrait;

/**
 * Test description.
 *
 * @group my_module
 */
class MyModuleTests extends ViewTestBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected $defaultTheme = 'olivero';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected static $modules = [
    'views',
    'my_module',
    'my_module_tests',
  ];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static $testViews = [
    'my_module_test_content',
  ];


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp($import_test_views = TRUE, $modules = ['views_test_config']): void {
    parent::setUp($import_test_views, ['my_module_tests']);

    //$this->configImporter();
    $account = $this->drupalCreateUser(['access content']);
    $this->drupalLogin($account);
    // ...
  }

  /**
   * Assert that the my_module installed correctly.
   */
  public function testModuleInstalls() {
    // If we get here, then the module was successfully installed during the
    // setUp phase without throwing any Exceptions. Assert that TRUE is true,
    // so at least one assertion runs, and then exit.
    $this->assertTrue(TRUE, 'Module installed correctly.');
  }

}

But the test fails at the install hook

Drupal\Tests\my_module\Functional\MyModuleTests::testModuleInstalls
web\modules\custom\my_module\my_module.install:20


Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\SchemaIncompleteException: No schema for
views.settings

And i am having a hard time trying to fix it or even understand why, the schema for views.settings is existent at core/modules/views/config/schema/views.schema.yml
Why is it that i get the error? Shouldnt the "views" module be enabled as well?
What do i have to do in order to make it work?

What's line 20 of my_module.install doing? I'm assuming something with Views but might be useful to see

Sorry, line 20 of my_module.install is $config->save() from the lines i posted in the question

Okay i found the issue, i did not have the dependency to views module in the my_module.info.yml
after adding
dependencies:
  - drupal:views

the error disappeared and the tests were successfull
